# Using this keyword with strict mode with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, strict

I am trying to use the "this" keyword inside a function, this works

```
var test = function(){
    console.log(this); //console logs the window object
}
(function(){
    test();
});
```

However when I try and use strict mode this is undefined?

```
'use strict';
var test = function(){
    console.log(this); //undefined
}
(function(){
    test();
});
```

I wish to know if its possible to access the this keyword from inside function in strict mode?

Any help highly appreciated.

So for anyone facing same issue
This works

```
'use strict';
var test = {
    fname:'kalesh',
    check: function(){
        console.log(this.fname);
    }
};
(function(){
    test.check();
})();
```

It appears that in strict mode have to be inside an object to use this keyword and not only inside function

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to apply the window object to this, you can use `call(window)` or `apply(window)`

Apply: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp

Call: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp

Comment: Not what I was looking for but your link pointed me to the right asnwer